# Como deixar o acesso a minha API aberta para consulta

Tags: java, angular, api, spring, rest

Tenho uma aplicaçao construída em Angular2+ e estou precisando deixar uma rota aberta para consulta externa, sem precisar logar na aplicaçao:

**Resource JAVA**

```
@GetMapping("/clientes/consulta/{identificador}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.ANONYMOUS + "\")")
    public ResponseEntity<ClienteDTO> getClienteByIdentificador(@PathVariable String identificador) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Cliente by identificador : {}", identificador);
        Optional<ClienteDTO> clienteDTO = clienteService.findByIdentificador(identificador);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(clienteDTO);
    }
```

**service TS**

```
public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/clientes';
findByIdentificador(identificador: string): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    return this.http.get<ICliente>(`${this.resourceUrl}/consulta/${identificador}`, { observe: 'response' });}
```

**Security Configuration**

```
.antMatchers("/api/clientes/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: desse modo funciona, descobri aqui.
Precisa colocar acima da linha que pede authenticaçao para toda a api. Aí essa rota nao vai pedir mais autenticaçao.

.antMatchers("/api/clientes/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma aplicação Angular e setei a url de cada classe na camada serviço.

Exemplo:

produto.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Produto } from '../models/produto.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProdutoService {
  url = 'http://localhost:56133/api/Produto';
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  //Selecionar todos produtos
  getProdutos() : Observable<Produto[]>{
    return this.http.get<Produto[]>(this.url);
  }

  //Apagar produto
  deleteProduto(produto: Produto) {
    return this.http.delete<Produto>(this.url + '/' + produto.id, this.httpOptions)
  }

  //Adicionar produto
  addProduto(produto: Produto): Observable<Produto> {
    return this.http.post<Produto>(this.url, JSON.stringify(produto), this.httpOptions)
  }

  //Atualiza um carro
  updateProduto(produto: Produto): Observable<Produto> {
    return this.http.put<Produto>(this.url + '/' + produto.id, JSON.stringify(produto), this.httpOptions)  
  }
}
```

GitHub https://github.com/rodrigofurlaneti/vendas-ng/tree/master/vendas-ng/src/app